# Trying to add two tables into one JFrame, but only one appears

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jtable

I'm trying to add two tables into my frame, but I only get one. I tried to use different positions in BorderLayouts, but still don't get the final result. My code is below:

```
     private JFrame f = new JFrame("List of cars");

    //           [SIZE]
    f.setSize(700, 600);

    //           [TABLE]
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable table = new JTable(model);

    model.addColumn("GROUP 1");

    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(30, 20));

    JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(table);

    JPanel listPahel = new JPanel();
    listPahel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    listPahel.add(jScrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    listPahel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50, 10, 400, 500));
    listPahel.validate();

    //-----------------

    DefaultTableModel model2 = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable table2 = new JTable(model2);

    model2.addColumn("GROUP 2");

    table2.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(30, 20));

    JScrollPane jScrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(table2);

    JPanel listPahel2 = new JPanel();
    listPahel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    listPahel2.add(jScrollPane2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    listPahel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(200, 20, 20, 20));
    listPahel2.validate();

    f.add(listPahel);
    f.add(listPahel2);


    f.setVisible(true);
```

I always get the second table, but I need to get both.

Comment: I've been inclined to use a 1 column 2 row `GridLayout`

Comment: listPahel and listPahel2 are two different containers with two different BorderLayouts.  The constraints applied in one container will not affect the layout of the other container.  Instead of using BorderLayout constraints there, pass BorderLayout constraints as second arguments to your `f.add` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

You didn't say how you wanted the `JTables` arranged on your page, so I put them side by side.  Here's the example GUI I came up with.

[image: Example]

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that all Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I separated the creation of the `JFrame` from the creation of the two `JPanels` that hold the `JTables`.  The `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`.  I defined each of the two `JPanels` to have a `BorderLayout`.

The two `JPanels` each have a `JScrollPane` placed in the CENTER of their `BorderLayout`.

The two `JPanels` are placed in the WEST and EAST of the `JFrame` `BorderLayout`.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TwoJTablesGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TwoJTablesGUI());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Two JTables GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createJTable1Panel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(createJTable2Panel(), BorderLayout.EAST);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createJTable1Panel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.addColumn("GROUP 1");

        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createJTable2Panel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.addColumn("GROUP 2");

        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

}
```